# Why won't my Levitron Z-Wave dimmer switch turn the lights off?

Tags: switch, dimmer-switch

Recently purchased and installed a Z-Wave Dimmer switch which seemed to be an easy installation. However, the only way I can get the light to turn off is to enable the air gap on the switch. If the air gap isn't open, the light is on no matter what.

Neither the physical switch on the dimmer nor turning off the switch off via zwave turns off the light--only the air gap.

White bundle are neutrals. 
Blacks are hot.
White/Red combo is to the light.
Green is ground.

[image: photo of setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you described and showed, and assuming that it was just a regular single pole switch you replaced that worked fine before, the wiring does look correct (though I'd skip the extra black pigtail wire that goes between the white and orange wire nuts).

Sounds like the switch itself is defective, and the best course of action would be to exchange it where you purchased it. Remember, these things have a fair bit of electronics in them, so it can happen. Sorry for your luck.

Comment: Thanks, gregmac for your input. I'll try to pick up another switch and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Confirmed, Gregmac's solution. Faulty switch. Similiar switch installed exactly same way worked as directed.